# Questions asking for programming help

Tags: discussion, scope

On Stack Overflow each and every programming question [must include a minimum piece of code including test data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise it gets closed down.

What is our policy regarding this ?

I raised the flag on this question (which was accepted) [PV code help](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9385/computing-isentropic-potential-vorticity-from-hybrid-sigma-pressure-levels/16060#16060) that you either need to break it down into smaller questions or give an example that we can run on our machine.

Yet again another question has been asked today - [Temperature advection help](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/temperature-advection-using-finite-differences-with-gridded-data) that does not give any data for us to run.

In the past casey (one of the moderators) used to ask for external links to data files so that we can run the code on our box. Should that be our policy or should we let incomplete questions be the norm ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to ask the OP to upload the code or (minimum verifiable example) MVE on github and also provide for a link to the data files(minimum data required to run the MVE) not the entire netCDF file. People on this site could then download the code and data and come up with suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, as it is always required at stackoverflow, when it is code, show your code. This is the way it works. Others correct your code and third users use the clean one. The user is happy and the planet remains cleaner while answer use to optimize the computer expenditure.
Anyhow, sometimes they ask for specifical database, datasets and it may be ok just saying "I have tried this dataset but it don't works".